Two skips after attack
If I play two skip turn cards after attack card is played against me, does it mean that the next person has to take two turns?

No. Skips don't push the current turn onto the next player, they end the current turn and move to the next player in turn order. Because of the attack card being played, the next player is still you, so a second skip card would end that turn too and go right back to the regular turn of the player next to you.
